# SSRS Deploying Reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, deployment

I have a ssrs package within visual studio I have set up configuration to deploy to the report server. I right click on the report I want to deploy and is successfully deploys. but it also deploys all other reports within my project. what to I need to change in configuration settings to just deploy the selected report and not all of them?

Comment: If you want to just deploy one report, or a selection, then just select the report(s) you want to deploy. Of course deploying a project is going to deploy all the reports in the project, what else would you expect? If you were copying a directory you would expect all the files to come with it as well, not just some.

Comment: I do just click on the one I want to deploy but it is deploying all of them

Comment: What actions are you taking? To deploy a single report you simply right click the report in the Solution Explorer and click Deploy. This **will not** deploy your whole project. This functionality has been the same since BIDS, and is still the case in SSDT 2017. If you, when selecting deploy, your whole project is deploying, then you have your project selected as well.

Comment: its ok - I have been doing it right. its just on the report server its showing last modified for all reports to be the time and date of when I deploy one report

Comment: You are doing it right: it was a bug in SSDT to deploy all reports rather than just the one you chose.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in an earlier version of SSDT within Visual Studio. It is fixed in the current version (15.5.1 for VS 2017, 17.4 for VS 2015)